# Assign Series to DataFrame by multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]], index = [['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'] ], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

     A  B  C
a b  1  2  3
  b  1  2  3
  b  1  2  3
  b  1  2  3
```

And I have Series:

```
df_b = pd.Series(data = [1,2,3, 4], index = [['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3'] ])

a  b     1
   b1    2
   b2    3
   b3    4
```

I am trying to assign Series to DataFrame

```
    idx = df_a.index.intersection(df_b.index)
    df_a.loc[idx]['new_column'] = df_b.loc[idx]
```

But i get:

```
     A  B  C
a b  1  2  3
  b  1  2  3
  b  1  2  3
  b  1  2  3
```

And I expect to get:

```
     A  B  C new_column
a b  1  2  3   1
  b  1  2  3   1
  b  1  2  3   1
  b  1  2  3   1
```

Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: What does `new_column` represents?

Comment: @DanielMesejo It's the data from the Series: df_a.loc[idx]['new_column'] = df_b.loc[idx]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign directly. Series assignment *by default* aligns by index:

```
df_a['new_column'] = df_b

print(df_a)

     A  B  C  new_column
a b  1  2  3           1
  b  1  2  3           1
  b  1  2  3           1
  b  1  2  3           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning directly is probably the way to go. You could also use `merge` if you convert your series to a dataframe:

```
>>> df_a.join(df_b.to_frame('new_column'))
     A  B  C  new_column
a b  1  2  3           1
  b  1  2  3           1
  b  1  2  3           1
  b  1  2  3           1
```